# Defining a module_function in Ruby

Tags: ruby

*Note: This question has been posted already at [Ruby-Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6876455) without getting an answer*

Consider this module:

```
module MM
  def f
  end
  def self.g
  end
  module_function :f
end
```

Both, `f` and `g`, are module functions, and can be called as

```
MM::f
MM::g
```

Is it just a matter of taste, or might there be good reasons to choose
one way of defining a module function over the other?

I am aware, that there *is* a difference, when I am using the module as
a mixin:

```
class CC
  include MM
end
```

In this case, `f` is available also as an instance method within `CC`, while
`g` is not. However, this doesn't look to me as a particularily
interesting feature: If I design a module to be used as a mixin to a
class, I don't see why I would use module_function. Are there other
reasons why I would favorize either `self.FUNCTION` or `module_function`
when defining a module function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Doc](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/module_function):

> **module_function** creates module functions for the named methods. These functions may be
>   called with the module as a receiver, and also become available as
>   **instance methods** to classes that mix in the module. Module functions
>   are copies of the original, and so may be changed independently. **The
>   instance-method versions are made private**. If used with no arguments,
>   subsequently defined methods become module functions.

Basically, *module_function* is a way of **using module methods without mix-in the module into a class**.

The difference is that if you mix-in a module which uses `module_function`, the mixed-in methods will become *private instance methods* (but they will be public class methods of the declaring module). So, in your example, `f` becomes private instance method when module `MM` is mixed-in to the class `CC`, but can also be used as: `MM.f`.

When you have:

```
module MM
  def f
  end
  module_function :f
end
```

then you can use `MM.f` without mix-in the `MM` module into the `CC` class. But, if you don't use:

```
module_function :f
```

You can always mix-in the module `MM` into the `CC` class using:

```
class CC
  include MM
end
```

and can use method `f` as an instance method of the objects of `CC` class.

IMO, you don't really have any better reason to use `module_function` in general. If you want to have your module methods as instance methods of a class, then just include the module into the class (mix-in the module into the class) as shown in the above example.

And, for defining `static`/`utility` methods, you should do:

```
module MM
  def self.g
  end
end
```

or, you can even do this:

```
module MM
  extend self

  def g
  end
end
```

and then use the method like this: `MM.g` without mix-in the module. So, you don't really need to use `module_function`.